# Variable number of column in multicols, including a single one

Tags: conditionals, multicol

I'd like to call `multicols` with a parameter being the number of column and allow this parameter to take the value 1, like in this minimal working example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\newcommand{\varcols}[1]{%
\ifnum#1=1\lipsum\else{\begin{multicols}{#1}\lipsum\end{multicols}}\fi
}

\begin{document}
\varcols{3} 
\end{document}
```

but the problem is that it forces me to write my text (here `\lipsum`) two times, which is of course not desirable.

I tried another solution, but unfortunately without success :

```
\newcommand{\varcols}[1]{%
\ifnum#1=1\relax\else{\begin{multicols}{#1}}\fi
\lipsum
\ifnum#1=1\relax\else{\end{multicols}}\fi
}
```

but this fails : `!Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `\else` code is

```
{\begin{multicols}{#1}}
```

with spurious brace group around the begin. You just want

```
\begin{multicols}{#1}
```

and similarly for the end case,